# Mongoose can't connect: Error: querySrv ENOTIMP mongodb.tcp.cluster1-owfxv.mongodb.net

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, kubernetes

Mongoose can't connect to mogodb Atlas. It every times give me this error:

```
 Error: querySrv ENOTIMP _mongodb._tcp.cluster1-owfxv.mongodb.net
```

I am running inside kubernetes cluster inside minikube locally.
If I run project directly then it works perfectly but with minikube it alwasy give me error.

Following is my code:

```
  const url = "mongodb+srv://name:password@cluster1-owfxv.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true";

    const mongoDbOptions = {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        reconnectTries: 10,
        autoReconnect: true

    };
    mongoose.connect(url, mongoDbOptions).then((r) => { }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

Error message is not so clear to me. Its strange that it works directly but with kubernetes cluster it does not work.

I will really appreciate for any contribution.

Comment: The error basically means your application cannot reach the external address. This would essentially be caused by "network settings" on the running container. As such, IMHO questions on "connectivity and configuration" really should be asked on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com) as a more appropriate platform for something that is not really programming, or related to something that needs to be fixed in the application code itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using connection string compatible with mongo driver 2.2.12 or later i.e. one with mongodb://username:password@host1:port,host2:port,host3:port/databaseName

It's not clear why connection to mongodb is not working with new url.

Comment: I am not using any mongo driver directly. I am using mongoose only.

Comment: Mongoose uses mongo driver internally. Just try with the old connection string and see if it works.

Comment: I am not sure what is my old connection string. I just have latest connection string.

Comment: Go to atlas dashboard and you will find old connection string there

Comment: Oh! Man you are Genius and Life saver. This worked for me perfectly. 
I was stuck in this for more than 15 days but you solved my problem within a minute. Thank you so much. I really appreciate.

By the way, I was just curious to know that why latest connection string was not working? and what can we do to make latest connection string work? I was using latest version of Mongoose.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am not sure why the new connection strings are not working properly. There is some issue with network settings when used in kubernetes. I don't think it has anything to do with mongoose. If you would try to connect normally outside kubernetes you would connect without any problem.

Comment: Yes that's right. it works well outside kubernetes. anyways, once again, Thank you very much. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Yeah, I ran into the same problem.  Was able to get things running with docker-compose, but could not get a connection to MongoDB Atlas once I was running K8s on MiniKube.  So, I changed to the old connection string and it worked.  Thank You.  Before I came to this solution - which I hope to understand why - I did get some connection success by setting the dnsPolicy to 'None' for my pods and then providing the openDNS nameservers under the dnsConfig.  But then that broke the auto-IP lookup between pods and so I had to use service IP addresses rather than '<service>.default'.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Using older url, as stated by @cEeNikC, even works when mongoose is giving the following error-

```
Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.aq9un.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19) {
  errno: 'ETIMEOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.aq9un.mongodb.net'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to your cluster setting and enable access from all IP addresses (if you doing this for a learning purpose because it's not safe) .

Answer (score 0):

I add this "&w=majority" and worked:

Before: mongodb+srv://:@sdq25.lepde.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true
After: mongodb+srv://:@sdq25.lepde.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&**w=majority**